# How many minutes is it before 12 noon?

Tags: mathematics, time

This puzzle is a one I met in an IQ test. I believe it's tricky, however, the concept is quite simple.

> How many minutes is it before 12 noon if 68 minutes ago it was three times as many minutes past 10 a.m.?

Suppose x is the minutes before 12 noon.

*Now I have 3 meanings with 3 different solutions*

1. … if 68 minutes ago it (*then*) was three times as many minutes past 10 am (*now*)

   x + 68 = 3 $\times$ (120 - x) $\rightarrow$ x = 73 min
2. … if 68 minutes ago it (*now*) was three times as many minutes past 10 am (*then*)

   x = 3 $\times$ [120 - (x + 68)] $\rightarrow$ x = 39 min
3. … if 68 minutes ago it (*then*) was three times as many minutes past 10 am (*then*)

   x + 68 = 3 $\times$ [120 - (x + 68)] $\rightarrow$ x = 22 min

But the model answer I was told was 13 which I see definitely wrong. What's wrong with my understanding of this *ambiguous* puzzle?

---

### *edit*...

My interpretations are backed up on this usage of [**"times as many"**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7894/x-times-as-many-as-or-x-times-more-than/7897)

p.s Please, state how much you agree with **potential interpretations**?

---

### *edit #2*...

Source of confusion reduces to how to interpret the phrase: **x is three times as y**

My interpretation was: **[x is (equals) three times as ($\times$ 3) y](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7894/x-times-as-many-as-or-x-times-more-than/7897) $\Rightarrow$ x = 3 $\times$ y**

The opposite interpretation was: **x is three times ($\times$ 3) as (equals) y $\Rightarrow$ x $\times$ 3 = y**

Comment: https://xkcd.com/169/

Comment: @Wen1now I totally agree :).

Comment: The correct interpretation of "times as many" is exactly as in the link you give, but you're applying it wrong here. The first and second half of the puzzle are exactly parallel: (How many minutes // three times as many minutes), (is it // it was), (before 12 noon // past 10 a.m.). So it has to be 3*x = 120-(x+68), and the answer is 13 (as the answers below tell you).

Comment: *Clearly*, "three times as many minutes" refers to the most recent instance of "minutes"; 68. Therefore it's 4*68 minutes after 10AM right now, and the next noon is tomorrow. :(

Comment: Apparently I can't add an answer, but the trick to IQ tests is that the math is simple and they want to see that you won't be hung up on trivialities. There are 120 minutes between 10 and noon, subtract 68 minutes and you get 52, then divide by 4, and it's 13 minutes before noon.

Comment: @psmears I tend to be precise in my interpretation which is consistent with everyday math problems. Just make a quick survey of similar uses of *"times as many"* and you'll find my interpretation quite normal and popular. On the other hand, I really don't think your *"one-and-only"* interpretation a precise one.

Comment: @JFA I think this IQ question is an odd one, and wrongly put. To have a worded problem, it should be stated in a clearly unambiguous way, or at least to validate more than one answer. It's not tolerated in Mathematical problems to be ambiguous.

Comment: @psmears Again, look at this [problem](https://www.wyzant.com/resources/answers/14937/sheila_has_5_times_as_many_markers_as_dave_together_they_have_18_markers_how_many_markers_does_sheila_have) and the posted solution: **x has 5 times as many as y** solved as **x = 5y** *not* **y = 5x**. Besides, I think it's the logical interpretation.

Comment: Most people seem to be having no issue with interpreting this. Is this perhaps a language barrier issue? maybe somebody could translate this into your first language to help it make more sense.

Comment: @PeterL It's about interpreting the same structure in two opposite ways for the same conditions without differentiation. It has nothing to do with first and second languages.

Comment: @Samha': I agree with the interpretation in that link, and my answer agrees with it. Your answer 2 (the closest to being correct) has the *opposite* interpretation from your link. Perhaps something else in the wording is confusing you? (It's not to do with being mathematical or logical: I have many years experience of that, and the answer 13 is the mathematical/logical one; if you're getting other answers the problem lies somewhere else :-) )

Comment: For what it's worth, I honestly can't figure out how you get *any* of the three equations you list (and also got 13 before looking at any written answer here or your proposed answer).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand any of your three solutions.  None of them seem to be based on reasonable interpretations of the problem.  I can't imagine any possible interpretation of this question that would lead to any answer other than 13.

Comment: @DanielWagner I understand the two opposite ways of interpreting this answer, including yours, and I see them both potential ones of this puzzle. I'm just favoring my  interpretation which seems natural to me and more pertaining to the literal meaning.
Let me break that sentence down
***"... if 68 minutes ago it (minutes to noon) was (equals) three times (3 $\times$) as many minutes past 10 am (minutes past 10)"***
|| **(minutes to noon) = (minutes past 10) $\times$ 3**

Comment: @Samha' Aha, thanks for the clarification! Now the problem is clear: "it was" is a very idiomatic shortening of "the time was", and so idiomatic that it completely overwhelms any possible insertion of another antecedent for "it". So "it (minutes to noon)" would never cross the mind of most readers, in favor of "it (the time 68 minutes ago)".

Comment: @DanielWagner Further, your interpretation is equivalent to breaking down that sentence as:
***"... if 68 minutes ago it (minutes to noon) was three times ($\times$ 3) as (equals) many minutes past 10 am (minutes past 10)"* || (minutes to noon) $\times$ = (minutes past 10)**

Comment: @Samha' I think our comments crossed streams. In any case, I definitely wouldn't break down the sentence that way: the "it" is definitely referring to "the time 68 minutes ago", not "the number of minutes to noon". (Incidentally, this also follows the standard rule about "it": "it" always refers to the most recent noun phrase.)

Comment: @DanielWagner I intentionally dropped down the 68 term because it has no difference on the meaning of the two interpretations, but I knew it's there.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem The above comments sums up what causes the confusion.

Comment: @Samha': Your interpretation is not a valid interpretation of the English. You are giving the parts of the sentence meanings that they cannot grammatically have, and that is what is getting you confused. Would you like me to explain this in an answer for you?

Comment: @psmears The break-downs I mentioned earlier are to assist in catching the source of ambiguity. I am not using that literal-concrete way in interpreting English of course. That was clearing of what appears to be *subconscious* translations of words into mathematical inference for both meanings.

Comment: @Samha': I know you don't mean the breakdowns literally - they're just an aid in explaining how the sentence is understood, and they're very useful for that (thanks!). The thing is, your interpretation of the question just isn't possible in English. I think you're missing clues in the sentence that point to the correct interpretation. I can try to explain in an answer if you like. Do you think that would be useful?

Comment: @psmears It might be of help only If you think that this puzzle is ambiguous, or if you think that you understand what seems to you to be misleading me or anyone catching the same meaning as I do.

Comment: Your edit #2 seems very strange. Nobody is saying that "x is three times as [much as] y" would mean "y=3x".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Main answer

First, I'd like you to take a look at the example sentences from the two links you provided ([1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7894/x-times-as-many-as-or-x-times-more-than/7897), [2](https://www.wyzant.com/resources/answers/14937/sheila_has_5_times_as_many_markers_as_dave_together_they_have_18_markers_how_many_markers_does_sheila_have)):

> Jack has 3 times **as** many sweets **as** John.

> Sheila has 5 times **as** many markers **as** dave

Now, compare those to the sentence fragment you're trying to interpret:

> $x$ is 3 times **as** $y$

Notice anything different? The key difference here is that, in the examples "as" occurs *twice*, but in your fragment there is only one "as".

In fact, your fragment (assuming, as you are, that $x$ and $y$ are nouns) is not grammatical in English. It doesn't make sense. So we must look for another interpretation.

The construction in English works as follows:

> (*nounA*) is 3 times *as* (*quality*) *as* (*nounB*).

This is the form used in both your links. As I've mentioned, there are *two* instances of the word "as". In other languages we use different words for these two functions, so let's label them for clarity:

> (*nounA*) is 3 times as<sup>1</sup> (*quality*) as<sup>2</sup> (*nounB*).

The first, "as<sup>1</sup>", introduces a *quality* that is being compared (how tall, how heavy, how many markers, how many minutes past ten etc.), while the second, "as<sup>2</sup>", introduces *what is being compared* - the "baseline" for the comparison.

But, I hear you ask, there is only one "as" in the puzzle - so is it *as<sup>1</sup>* or *as<sup>2</sup>*?

Good question!

In English, in this sort of sentence, it is permissible to have just one "as" but only when that is an as<sup>1</sup>.<sup>*</sup> In this case, what we are comparing against is unstated and implicit - it must be inferred from the context, and is usually "the thing we are currently talking about". For example:

> - Fred is 3 times as tall. (As me? As a normal person? As he was yesterday? Depends what we're talking about.)
> - Jack has 3 times as many sweets. (As John? As me? As he did yesterday? Depends what we're talking about.)

It is *not* possible to have just an as<sup>2</sup>. You simply cannot say:

> - *The cat is 3 times as the dog.
> - *Fred is 3 times as Jack.

It doesn't make any sense; it is ungrammatical. So we can't read the puzzle like that - we must pick a different interpretation.

So:

- The quality being compared is "number of minutes past 10 a.m." - call that $y$
- It is three times something (so $y = 3z$)
- We don't immediately know what it is being compared *with*. So we don't know $z$; we need to work it out from the context.

Notice that the two clauses in the puzzle are somewhat parallel, in that they share a number of corresponding elements:

| (now) | How many minutes? | is it | before 12 noon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 68 minutes ago | three times as many minutes | it was | past 10 a.m. |

This is important, because the parallelism gives a clue to the reader to understand elements in the second half in a similar way to how they were understood in the first half.

In particular, the "many minutes" in both parts gives a clue that this is what is being compared. This makes sense because, since it's what the puzzle's question asks, it is what we're currenly talkign about. In short, $z=y$.

(In fact there is a possibility, though it is less likely given the parallelism, that the puzzle intends you to compare the number of minutes since 10 a.m. as of 68 minutes ago with the number of minutes since 10 a.m. now – but @Rob has shown in his answer that this interpretation is impossible from a mathematical point of view.)

### * It is possible to have just an as<sup>2</sup> in other types of sentence, but not in sentences of the form "X is 3 times as Y".

## Other stuff

Here are some other notes on the puzzle that you may find helpful - there are a few other pointers that confirm this interpretation above any other:

The first thing to note is that the question is made up of two main clauses, joined by "if":

- How many minutes is it before 12 noon?
- 68 minutes ago it was three times as many minutes past 10 a.m.

> How many minutes is it before 12 noon?

Concentrating on the first clause: this is simple enough, and you have interpreted it correctly (it is asking for $x$ where the current time is $x$ minutes before 12 noon). But do note the following:

- Clue: the verb is "is", which indicates that it is asking about the present. There's no specific word to say "now", but none is needed.
- The subject is "it". This is an [impersonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impersonal_verb) construction; the pronoun "it" doesn't really refer to anything specific: it just refers to the general context. In this case, however, we can replace it with "the time" without changing the meaning.

> if

So far a question has been posed (What is $x$?), but we don't have enough information to find it. The "if" signals that the next clause will give further constraints that may allow us to narrow down the answer. It could equally be replaced with "given that".

> 68 minutes ago

This is adverb phrase indicating the timeframe for the verb. Clue: it indicates that the context for the verb is a specific time in the past - in fact, 68 minutes into the past. Note that this phrase is *not* the subject of the sentence - though in another context it could be - because it is followed by "it" (the actual subject). Unlike in some languages, English does not allow inserting a subject pronoun that refers to an already-mentioned subject in the same clause (we don't say "*the dog it barked"), so "68 minutes ago" cannot be the subject.

> it

As already mentioned, this is the subject. Again, this is an impersonal construction - "it" refers to the context of the verb and (as already established) this means the same as "the time" [at the time of the verb].

> was

The verb. Clue: this is past tense, so *must* be referring to a time in the past. Unlike some languages, for factual "if" clauses such as this, the tense in English is natural - so a past tense implies a reference to the past, whereas in other languages a present tense interpretation is also possible. (Note that things are different for counterfactual "if" clauses.) This is consistent with the fact that, as already mentioned, the timeframe of this verb has been established as "68 minutes ago".

> three times as many minutes past 10 a.m.

This is the complement of the verb "was", telling us what the time was in the timeframe of the verb, as a number of minutes past 10 a.m. How many minutes? Let's call that $y$. What is $y$? We don't know exactly, but it is "three times as many minutes". As discussed above, this is an *as<sup>1</sup>*, and a number of things point to the implied object of comparison being $x$. So $y=3x$.

Comment: @bobble: Thanks for the edit - Markdown tables didn't exist back in 2017 when this answer was written :)

Answer (score 12):

I believe the interpretation the question setter wanted was:

> How many minutes is it before 12 noon if 68 minutes ago it was three times as many minutes past 10 a.m. **as how many minutes are currently left to 12 noon**?

Therefore, if x is the number of minutes to noon then 4x+68=120 so x=13. The only reason I am interpreting it this way is working backwards from the answer. The chances of anybody interpreting the question this way are tiny.

[image]
(from [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/169), of course)

Comment: 4x + 68 = 120 $\rightarrow$ 120 - (x + 68) = 3x
This is equivalent to saying: **the minutes past 10 am, 68 minutes ago, equal 3 times as many minutes before 12 noon.**

Comment: @Samha' I'm not sure if you're disagreeing or agreeing with the answer

Comment: disagreeing, this is opposed to what the puzzle states.

Comment: @Rob The puzzle says **the minutes to 12 noon, 68 minutes ago, equal 3 times as many minutes past 10 am**

Comment: @Samha' That's not what the question says. It says the *current* minutes to noon is the same as 3 times the minutes past 10, as of 68 minutes ago.

Comment: @Rob So, you agree to the meaning number 2 in my solution?

Comment: @Samha' No, with this answer's solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61464/discussion-between-samha-and-rob).

Comment: This was exactly the way (and the only way) I interpreted the question.

Comment: I don't think you can republish xkcd comics here without attribution. (Actually, I'm not really sure that you can republish them here at all, since they have a NC clause.)

Comment: "The chances of anybody interpreting the question this way are tiny." - This is exactly how I interpreted it. I personally find it really hard to follow the OPs logic in any of their three examples.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Hmm... Well, I have [seen it done before](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30/what-is-the-optimal-first-move-in-tic-tac-toe/47#47), and the xkcd website does say that 'you're free to copy and share these comics (but not to sell them)'. But maybe you're right, I've got no idea.

Comment: @Wen1now The main point here is attribution. On the page you link, they write that the comic comes from xkcd, while you don't.

Comment: Whatever about the actual question, I'm having difficulty understanding the xkcd comic... can someone explain it to me?

Comment: @DCON http://explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/169

Comment: That's f***ing stupid. Excuse my french. Like, by including "That end in" it makes the following response completely invalid. Why couldn't they use the classic "Immediate is a hard word to spell. How do you spell it? I-T!" at least that one makes sense. I do appreciate what the comic is trying to say but damn, bad delivery.

Answer (score 10):

> How many minutes is it before 12 noon if 68 minutes ago it was three
>   times as many minutes past 10 a.m.?

Lets break down the question.

> How many minutes is it

We have to find an unknown amount of minutes. Lets call this x.

> before 12 noon

Now we have our first time, which is x minutes before 12.

> if 68 minutes ago it was

There is a second time, which is 68 minutes earlier than the first time.

> three times as many minutes

Three times as many as what? This could refer to the original x minutes, or the 68 minutes just mentioned. It doesn't make sense to me to use 68, which mean this refers to 3x minutes.

> past 10 a.m.?

Our second time is 3x minutes past 10.

To make an equation I will use 10 am as a base time. From 10 am to the first time there are $120 - x$ minutes. From 10 am to the second time there are 3x minutes, then another 68 minutes to the second time for $3x + 68$ minutes.

$120-x=3x+68\Rightarrow x=13$

Comment: So, how would you accommodate to this [interpretation for **"times as many"**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7894/x-times-as-many-as-or-x-times-more-than/7897)

Comment: @Samha' I don't see any different interpretation of "times as many". That question discusses the ambiguity of "times more", which is not used here.

Comment: The example used in that link is *"A has 3 **times as many** sweets as B, and where B has 5 sweets, then, A has 3 $\times$ 5 = 15 sweets"*. And that's is the meaning I get to understand up till now, which is the converse of yours.

Comment: More plainly, **A = 3 $\times$ B**, not **B = 3 $\times$ A**.

Comment: @Samha' ok, I finally see what you mean. The problem isn't with "times as many" but because the question doesn't specify if it's "A is 3 times as many as B" or "B is 3 times as many as A". I've been staring at the question for 15 min now, and I still don't think your interpretation is valid, at least without adding a word, like "three times as many **as** minutes past 10". Even if your interpretation is correct as it is, it would be a very odd way to phrase it.

Comment: Frankly, your interpretation seems just as odd to me, while my interpretation is very normal to me, and I think it has something to do with mathematical precision. But, *wouldn't it be the same to say **as many minutes past 10 am, 3 times**? which could strengthen your intuition of what I mean.*

Comment: @Samha' Huh? How is that the converse? Both usages align with each other. B = minutes before noon, A = minutes after 10, which is 3 × B.

Comment: "But, wouldn't it be the same to say **as many minutes past 10 am, 3 times**?" Except now the English is even more awkward, and turns multiplication into a frequency (something occurred 3 times, rather than A multiplied by three). If we were to correct it and say "**as many minutes past 10 am times 3**", you should still parse it as the answer given here. All you've done is turn 3 x minutes into minutes x 3.

Answer (score 7):

I think the trouble you are having is not with the interpretation of "times as many" but with what you think the second "it" refers to. The "it" is somewhat abstract, like "it is raining", or "it is 5 o'clock". It does not refer to anything specific, but is a placeholder for the conditions of that particular time and place.

The final part of the question is saying "it was y minutes past 10 o'clock". That 'it' does not refer to a specific number of minutes, but to what the conditions were 68 minutes ago.

So the question should be read as:
It is now x minutes before noon, and what is x if 68 minutes ago it was 3x minutes past 10am?

This leads to the answer x=13 as others have noted.

Comment: A small nitpick, while we don't conciously think of what "it" is, it's actually quite concrete in most cases. It* is often helpful to ask the question to which the statment answers:
+ What is the weather like? - it (weather) is raining.
+ What time is it? - it ( the time) is 5 O'clock
+ What kind of facts do we know about crocodiles? - it (this fact) is well known that crocodiles can exit the river.
(*) the process of asking.

Comment: @mr23ceec: I disagree: you could perfectly well say "last night it rained", but saying "\*last night the weather rained" would be very odd. It's just an [impersonal verb](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impersonal_verb).

Answer (score 3):

Here is my sample solution

> 720 - x - 68 = x * 3 + 600
>  720 - 600 - 68 = x * 3 + x
>  52 = 4x
> 52 / 4 = x
> x = 13

Comment: You've just retyped the equations of the other two answers. Can you extract the flaws in my solutions and justify your interpretation?, respecting my [backed up interpretation.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7894/x-times-as-many-as-or-x-times-more-than/7897)

Answer (score 3):

It's the second option that you mentioned

> … if 68 minutes ago it (now) was three times as many minutes past 10 am (then)
>
> x = 3 × [120 - (x + 68)] → x = 39 min

But you're multiplying the wrong thing. The right side of the equasion is X3 larger, so you should write

```
3 × X = 120 - (X + 68)
4X = 52
X = 13
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two interpretations of this question that I can see:

> How many minutes is it before 12 noon if 68 minutes ago it was three times as many minutes past 10 a.m.?

1. The number of minutes between 10am and 68 minutes ago, equals three times the number of minutes from now until noon
2. The number of minutes between 10am and now, equals three times the number of minutes between 10am and 68 minutes ago.

Now, the second one is interesting, because it opens up the possibility of '10am' being deliberately ambiguous. It could refer to 10am yesterday. Let's investigate that possibility.

For the second case to be true, we have two options:

1. Both cases refer to the same 10am
2. 68 minutes ago goes past 10am, and thus each point in time refers to a different 10am.

The first cannot be true. A time closer to 10am (68 minutes ago) cannot *also* be further away from 10am (3x).

The second cannot be true, either. Three times the number of minutes means we can have a *maximum* difference of 204 minutes (68 * 3) between the two 10am's. Clearly, that's not the case.

So we've eliminated ambiguity #2. Thus, the question must be:

> The number of minutes between 10am and 68 minutes ago, equals three times the number of minutes from now until noon

Which is solved by (let y = the number of minutes past 10am, and x = the number of minutes from *now* until noon):

y = 120 - (x + 68)
x = y / 3

x = (120 - (x + 68)) / 3
3x = 120 - x - 68
3x = 52 - x
4x = 52
x = 13

Comment: You have said *"... equals three times the number of minutes between 10am ..."*, but x = y / 3 means *"Number of minutes from now until noon, equals **one third** of the number of minutes between 10am and 68 minutes ago"*

Comment: @Samha' Sorry, yes - I had it backwards in the text. I've edited

Comment: Well, the same error holds

Comment: @Samha' How so? The number of minutes of now to noon is one third of the minutes between 10am and 68 minutes ago. Which is the exact same thing as saying the number of minutes between 10am and 68 minutes ago is three times that of the number of minutes between now and noon.

Comment: Regardless of my disagreeing, you didn't edit the part: *"The number of minutes from now until noon, equals three times the number of minutes between 10am and 68 minutes ago"*

Comment: Well, it seems that you do justify your understanding to whatever the answer is. I mean, it's not like a genuine interpretation.

Comment: @Samha' That's untrue - I fail to see any other legitimate interpretation of the question; there's only two possibilities, and we can prove one of them to be unsolvable

Comment: Take a look at the usage of expression *"times as many"* in this English-linguistic forum. It favors my interpretation, in which the **precedent = *whatever* times the subsequent.**
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7894/x-times-as-many-as-or-x-times-more-than/7897

Comment: @Samha' The thing you're missing is that the "it" at the beginning is separate from the second "it". The first "it" = x = minutes before noon. The second it = y = 120 - x - 68. They then state that y is three times as many minutes [as x]. Thus, y = 3x. This lines up with the "precedent" whatever times the subsequent.

Comment: @DavidLiu **How can *"it"* be used to refer to something wasn't mentioned yet?** Intuitively, pronouns are often used to refer to subjects already mentioned before, either the latter subjects, or a former one with an additional hint specific to the meant subject.

Comment: @Samha' Well that's just plain incorrect. 'What time is it?' Is a perfect example. Your question is really turning into an English language question instead of a puzzling question.

Comment: @Samha' That's not necessarily true at all. If that were the case, then the puzzle wouldn't make any sense in the first place. According to your rules, even within the first part of the puzzle, "How many minutes is it before noon?", "it" can't be used to refer to the current time, as "current time" hasn't been mentioned yet. Pronouns are simply things that can be inferred through context. If you ask a stranger, "How is it going today?", any English speaker will know you're asking about how their **day** is going, even though "it" is not specified.

Answer (score 1):

Well yeah, the text itself doesn't specify exactly that it is right now... However my first idea still was `x = (120 -x -68)/3`, which would solve to 13.

120 is the total time difference.

x is the time we actually need to know

-x is the amount we are away from 12

-68 are the minutes which makes

/3  one third of the minutes now.